# TYPO3 v12: Trigger Action Over URL Parametes + ShortenURLs

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript

I'm trying to get an old plugin to work in TYPO3 v12 that shows a list of already send newsletters.
I am new to TYPO3 so I don't really understand how the controllers work.

The list view for the newsletter archive works but I have a problem displaying the detail pages.
The content of the newsletters is stored in a folder. The UID is the id of the content.

Currently my links look like this: `/detail?tx_newsletter%5Baction%5D=show&tx_newsletter%5Bcontroller%5D=NewsletterArchive&tx_newsletter%5Buid%5D=2195&cHash=5094bebe868a51e8e17afb0b9629ddc2`

The function to generate the link is the following:

```php
public function buildUrlByUidAction($uid) {
    $url = $this->uriBuilder
        ->reset()
        ->setTargetPageUid($this->settings['singlePid'])
        ->setCreateAbsoluteUri(true)
        ->uriFor(
            'show',
            [
                'uid' => $uid,
            ],
            'NewsletterArchive',
            'NL',
            'NewsletterArchiveList'
        );
    return $url;
}
```

```php
public function showAction($uid): ResponseInterface {
    $queryBuilder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)
    ->getQueryBuilderForTable('tt_content');
    $rows = $queryBuilder
        ->select('*')
        ->from('tt_content')
        ->where($queryBuilder->expr()
            ->eq('uid', $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter($uid, \PDO::PARAM_INT)))
        ->executeQuery()
        ->fetchAll();
    $row = NULL;
    if (count($rows)) {
        $row = $rows[0];

        $content = $row['bodytext'];

        $content = $this->cleanHtml($content);
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        $x = new \DOMDocument;
        $x->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
        $element = $x->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
        $newdoc = new \DOMDocument();
        $cloned = $element->cloneNode(TRUE);
        $newdoc->appendChild($newdoc->importNode($cloned, TRUE));
        $content = $newdoc->saveHTML();
        $content = $this->cleanHtml($content);

        $row['bodytext'] = $content;
    }
    $this->view->assign('row', $row);
    return $this->htmlResponse();
}
```

Both Functions are in the NewsletterArchiveController.php

There also is a `newsletter-archive.typoscript` which tries to trigger the show function:

```
lib.newsletterDetail >
lib.newsletterDetail = USER
lib.newsletterDetail {
  userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
  extensionName = NL
  pluginName = NewsletterArchiveList
  vendorName = Cawd
  controller = NewsletterArchive
  action = show
  switchableControllerActions {
    NewsletterArchive {
      1 = show
    }
  }
  view < plugin.tx_tmpl.view
  persistence < plugin.tx_tmpl.persistence
  settings < plugin.tx_tmpl.settings
}
```

Also is there a way to shorten the URLs?

I already tried to change the function name and also output content on the start of the showAction function. But non of my tries triggers the function.

Comment: Have a look at "routing"... https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/Routing/AdvancedRoutingConfiguration.html

Comment: Please show the `configurePlugin` function of `ext_localconf.php`. Is the plugin implemented on the page `detail`?

Comment: Please tell us the extension key and the foldername of the extension. (typo3conf/ext/???)

Answer (score 1):

`switchableControllerActions` is **deprecated** since TYPO3 v10.3 and was then removed in TYPO3 v12.0

https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/10.3/Deprecation-89463-SwitchableControllerActions.html#migration

You have to make some changes to your general extension setup and split your plugin into 2 plugins:

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

use Cawd\Newsletter\Controller\NewsletterArchive;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility;

defined('TYPO3') or die();

ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin (
    'Newsletter',
    'List',
    [
        NewsletterArchive::class => 'list'
    ]
);

ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin (
    'Newsletter',
    'Show',
    [
        NewsletterArchive::class => 'show'
    ]
);
```

```
lib.newsletterDetail >
lib.newsletterDetail = USER
lib.newsletterDetail {
  userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
  extensionName = Newsletter // not NL
  pluginName = Show          // The new Plugin name after splitting
  vendorName = Cawd
  controller = NewsletterArchive
  action = show
  view < plugin.tx_tmpl.view
  persistence < plugin.tx_tmpl.persistence
  settings < plugin.tx_tmpl.settings
}
```

Your `extensionName = NL` made no sense. The URL that you posted `/detail?tx_newsletter%5Baction%5D=show&` indicates that your extension lives in the folder `typo3conf/ext/newsletter/`, then your extension key would be `newsletter` and your ExtesionName `Newsletter`.